# ShareKit beta issues?

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, warnings, sharekit

I have made a so-called ShareKit beta, it has many fixes for warnings and also features a new SMS share component. This should dramatically be faster on all iOS's. Feel free to download it and of course add a comment if you would like to see a new feature added!

Thanks!

ChangeLog:

**1.0**: Fixed most warnings, made some improvements. Also fixed some leaks
**1.1**: Added SMS capabilities, fixed **all** warnings and leaks. And made other misc. fixes
**1.2** *Coming Soon*: Will feature the latest FBConnect so it works better on all iOSes. Look at the FBConnect change log to view their fixes in the latest version:
*Also keep in mind that iOS 5 Beta will encounter some problems but it is the iOS's fault. It should be 100% when the GM build comes out*

**Download Links**
Version 1.1 Site 1 *(Never Expires)*: http://www.mediafire.com/?pbuuf1j6cub3gj9
Version 1.1 Site 2 *(Never Expres)*: http://www.2shared.com/file/g33bKZ64/Beta-ShareKit_2.html

Also I give a very special thanks to: Sebastien Thuilliez for helping with some of the fixes and bugs!

Comment: Is this beta still available ? The link is broken.

Comment: Added new links, thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Does this new version involve sharing of **MULTIPLE** entities of same **TYPE** on same **SERVICE** as clicked in action sheet (i.e. by a single button action)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you didn't provided any sample source project, but only the library, I used this library on a project that is already using the ShareKit v0.2.1 (lib. which hasn't moved since a while).

Then I successfully logon to Facebook and send content using the SHKFacebook shareItem method, using your implementation. Both login & share content dialogs were displayed correctly.

Note that I had no warnings with FBConnect ( I always treat warnings as errors ).

For information :

- I am using a iPhone 4 with iOS 4.3.1 (8G4)
- the SHKActionSheet have a major issue with nested modal views ( main cause is the SHKviewDidDisappear method which is clearing the SHK currentHelper singleton currentView element and probably more) ... so perhaps you can add this issue to your road-map. ( haven't tested it with your implementation, but from the code diff. I made, it still seems to be the case )
- please consider updating your implementation version number which is still the same as the original version v0.2.1 ;)

Please let me know, if you need to do an extra particular test, because regarding the Facebook Sharer it seems to be fine.

Comment: thanks for the feedback! I would accept the answer but I am looking for bugs and fixes from the community, I am pretty nooby when it comes to Sharekit so if you find a fix, ill surely give you the bounty! I will update the version number later on or tomorrow!

Comment: Sure, but what is the bug you are facing with the facebook component cause while testing it, I had no problem.

Comment: I actually just re-tested it and it works. I guess when I was beta testing it a few days ago I had slow internet and thats why I thought it didn't work. If you find a bug, see if you can fix it and ill happily mark you as the accepted answer, and I'll post the updated version!

Comment: I have uploaded an updated of your library @ http://www.filesavr.com/BA3NJSDBC61C4GC that includes :

- a small fix on SHKFacebook class within the logout that was causing an exception (adding nil object to NSArray)

- I have added a SHKSMS sharer so you can share text content with SMS

- I have fixed the nested modal view issue and tested it with the SHKSMS class. I havent been able to test it against other sharers, cause I am out of time now. So think about doing a four-eyes check on it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent! When I tried FBConnect it works good as usual! The SMS feature is very useful which I will be implementing in the next few days! There are still 2 problems which I need fixed before I'll give you the bounty: 1. I get a warning in SHKFacebook.m which is 'Incompatible pointer types sending 'Class' to parameter of type 'id<FBSessionDelegate>' 2. I get a warning in the console when I show FBConnect and that is: 'NSURL default cookie store will be required for (null)' Once you fix those 2 problems, ill give you the bounty!

Comment: Also like with the other commenter said, do you know how to update FBConnect with it so it works better?

Comment: About FBConnect update, from my understanding the version you are using is enough for ShareKit usage, cause the Share feature is still working well. If you still want to update it, please report to the [related helping page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#ios). Now more about your warnings, can you tell me which iOS version you are targeting and which xCode version you are using, cause here with my xCode 3 targeting iOs 4.2, I have no warnings at all. Also please indicate me where exactly you get those warnings, and then I will try to help you more.

Comment: I get a warning in SHKFacebook.m which is 'Incompatible pointer types sending 'Class' to parameter of type 'id<FBSessionDelegate>
The warning happens when you do delegate:self in the +logout method.

Xcode 4.2 Developer Preview 7. Base SDK:iOS 5 Target Deployment: iOS 5

Comment: Also it seems that the Mail and SMS sharers don't dismiss their views when the cancel or done button are clicked :/

Comment: Could you please post back the library cause I am not on the same computer and the link seems to be broken now. Thanks

Comment: Updated version @ http://wikisend.com/download/190826/Beta-ShareKit.zip . SHKFacebook warning should be fixed (I don't have iOS5 installed yet). Regarding the NSURL warning, I found several report from testers and it seems to come from iOS beta version http://davidbits.blogspot.com/2011/09/nsurlrequest-default-cookie-store-will.html . I have double-checked and both SMS & Mail viewer are closing properly ensure you have updated the SHKItem class as in provided code. I guess you'd better validate your lib. with iOS 4 target cause using iOS beta will lead you to a lot of "beta-related" issues IMO

Comment: Yep, this new beta version fixed up those warnings. Also since you must be using iOS 4, and if you say it is working good for the SMS dismissing, then I think I will stay off of the SMS part for now until iOS 5 is out of beta. I agree though, that most of these issues are because of the ios5 beta so I think I will use it to the fullest extent when it is out of beta. For now though, I am just using the Facebook and Twitter part of it, and it seems to be working well! Also do you have a blog or something so you can post this on? I think we should have a place that everyone can easily download it

Comment: Also down the road, I think we should eventually update FBConnect so it is using their latest API's and so it will work with future iOSes.

Comment: I am sorry I don't have any blog or any community site where you can host your "updated" component. You should try to contact the ShareKit owners and ask them if you can pursue their work and use their space. I won't be able to help you right now for updating the FBConnect component cause I would be on holiday for two weeks in two days :) I guess, You should have a look yourself, this is not that complicated, specially for an update process .. this is more or less a matter of testing it, and fix few "compile issues". Good luck then. Hope my time was helpful to you.

Comment: And thanks for the bounty in any case ... if you still think I deserved it ;)

Comment: No problem! :) I did contact the original makers of ShareKit but there has been no answer back in email or tweet form :(
It looks like we will take over from here, I will try to update the FBConnect code but it would help if we had a sample project for ShareKit only so we could debug it easily without using our 'real' projects!
Maybe you could make a quick project and I can work on FBConnect from there? :]
Also feel free to up vote my question so I can gain some rep on this site!

Comment: I'm sorry, I won't have time to help you these days, cause I have a lot of stuff to complete before leaving. Just think about storing the package out from wikisend cause content will expire within a week.

Comment: Alright will do. I have moved this to a forum with a very elegant thread: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/89467-sharekit-beta-official.html

Comment: I am still trying to update the FBConnect part and I am having a lot of difficulty, do you have any idea on how to implement this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the FBConnect version released with share kit, which is very old and it has stopped working recently.

Furthermore you will need to readapt/redo the SHKFacebook class since most methods of the old API have changed in the new one.

I hope that this helps.

Comment: I would but I am a noob when it comes to FBConnect implementation, I have had so many problems with using it alone, thats why I am using Sharekit. If you know how to, please feel free to update it and ill be sure to give the credit for you for FBConnect.

Comment: Also like the other commenter said, I think the fbconnect integrated with share kit is sufficient even on the newest ios5 beta.

Comment: Since old Sharekit is unmaintained and the original FBConnect library has stopped working there is nothing much to do but replace it. Check the DemoApp of the Facebook API, it is not very hard to do basic posts following that scheme.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a project using the newer version of ShareKit. It works fine on iOS 4 devices but when I installed the app on an old iPod Touch (iOS 3.1.3) it crashes with the following error

dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMessageComposeViewController

Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/806901B4-D20C-42C7-9F34-0DE0FD4CA085/LER Mapper.app/LER Mapper

Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
 in /var/mobile/Applications/806901B4-D20C-42C7-9F34-0DE0FD4CA085/LER Mapper.app/LER Mapper

Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Not safe to call dlopen at this time.)

mi_cmd_stack_list_frames: Not enough frames in stack.

mi_cmd_stack_list_frames: Not enough frames in stack.

I fixed it by weak linking the MessageUI framework.

Comment: I think MFMessageController is available on in iOS 4 or up