# Fork for ShareKit under xCode 4.3 / iOS5?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sdk, sharekit

Is anyone aware of a fork for ShareKit for iOS5 / xCode 4.3 ? I am getting a large number of warnings compiling under 4.3 and bits of functionality are no longer working.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not worry about for most of the warnings since for the moment it still works, nevertheless the Facebook sharing API is broken. This was already discussed here: [ShareKit beta issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020310/sharekit-beta-problem/7260513#7260513)

iBrad Apps is improving it, I don't know very musch how the project works. The link is broken but if you google around for Beta-ShareKit.zip you will find plenty of copies of it like: http://www.mediafire.com/?pbuuf1j6cub3gj9

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks. There is also an issue with the cancel button not working on email screen etc - just so everyone knows.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend working with this fork of ShareKit:
https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit

It has a significant number of improvements over the canonical, including true support for iOS 5's Twitter integration.